# What are the advantages/disadvantages of making a Repository Persistence Ignorant?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

Usually, *Repositories* should know about the implementation details of which database we decided to use.

a) But what are advantages/disadvantages of also making *Repositories* Persistence Ignorant ( ie unaware what persistence medium is used for storing data ). Only advantage I can think of is that now same *Repository implementation* can be used regardless to which medium data is persisted

b) Assuming *Repository* is made *Persistence Ignorant*, then both the *Repository interface* and its implementation should reside within the *Domain assembly*?!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the whole point of using Repository pattern is to seperate Domain logic from the persistence logic, so, you can use the same domain implementation with different data stores. Thus it seems natural that the implementation of the repository must somewhat dependent on the database implementation.

a) The main disadvantage would be performance, I think. The more abstract away the repository library, you would need to design and implement more levels of abstraction, covering more cases. However, a specialized repository would perform better, knowing the full abilities of its underlying store.

Another disadvantage would be development & maintanence cost. I think these disadvantages outweigh any advantages of having a fully generic structure...

b)  For smaller projects my answer is "maybe" but for all other projects, it is a solid "No".  It does not have anything to do with Persistance Ignorance. A Best practice I always try to follow is seperation of concerns. If they are trying to do different things, then seperate them. It will save you from a lot of nightmare later.

Any further thoughts | ideas, I am willing to hear them too :)

Comment: "Another disadvantage would be development & maintanence cost." Why would making a repository unaware of persistence medium raise the development and maintenance costs ( I don't think having persistence medium agnostic repository breaks single responsibility principle )? I would expect just the opposite?!

Comment: It does not break SRP if its in a different assembly. However in (b) I think it does. The domain logic assembly has a different purpose than an abstraction layer that provides persistence agnostic data access.

"Another disadvantage would be development & maintanence cost." On this one, I considered if you go out of the scope and making it too generic (i.e. Supporting a large array of media). Of course, that would reduce costs if you stay within the bounds of the project. 

Thank you for pointing that out, I had to explain clearer :)

Comment: "It does not break SRP if its in a different assembly." So even if we make a Repository persistence agnostic, only the Repository interface can reside within Domain assembly, but not Repository implementation, else we break SRP ( or rather we break separation of concerns rule )?

Comment: Yes, the interests of domain logic and persistance agnostic library would still be different, it would be best to seperate them.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than making a Repository "Persistence Ignorant", you might wish to decouple a Repository interface from implementation. For example, a CustomerRepository can be implemented by both NHibernateCustomerRepository and EFCustomerRepository. This way, switching between implementations can be as easy as changing a configuration (at least, in a fantasy world). There are some real world uses for this: for example, certain client insists on using proprietary solution.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like out-thinking yourself. A classic repository pattern is meant to abstract the persistence details away from the implementation of value objects and entities, the fundamental building blocks in DDD. What is to be gained in making a repository persistence unaware, if it's point is to hide the persistence?

Some feel that they should abstract away the details of their persistence abstraction, e.g. allowing for a 'generic ORM' rather than 'NHibernate', but again here I think this is being too clever for your own good. You've got an `IRepository`, that's good enough. If you want an `NHibernateRepository` and an `EventStoreRepository`, go for it.

Comment: I assumed there's less code involved, since usually Repository sits on top of Data Mappers, which are aware of the persistence medium being used. As such, when you have N persistence mediums, you have to write "N Repository Implementations + N Data Mappers", while if Repository is unaware of a persistence medium, we only have to write "1 Repository + N Data Mappers"? Or is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: In the classic DDD formulation, each repository is very easy to write -- often just a concrete instantiation of a generic class. Then you add the queries you need, which you would have to do anyway.

Comment: Sorry for dragging this 1 - So if I understand you correctly, making Repository unaware of persistence medium is pointless mainly because it only takes a little bit more effort/code ( compared to writing a persistence medium agnostic Repository) to write Repositories aware of the persistence medium? 2 - Though I must confess I still don't quite understand what are the disadvantages of making a Repository unaware of a persistence medium?!